# Cannot get input value from md-input

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have this md-dialog which has an input. I'm passing the model of the input when I click the top up button but on my controller, it is undefined.

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Top Up User" ng-cloak>
  <md-dialog-content>
    <div class="md-dialog-content">
      <form>
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <label>Amount</label>
                <input required type="number" name="amount" ng-model="topup.amount" min="1"
                ng-pattern="/^1234$/" />
        </md-input-container>

        <md-dialog-actions layout="row" ng-show="!vm.loading">

            <md-button ng-click="vm.closeDialog()">
             Cancel
            </md-button>
            <md-button ng-click="vm.topUp(topup.amount)" style="margin-right:20px;">
              Top Up
            </md-button>
          </md-dialog-actions>

          <div layout="row" layout-align="space-around">
            <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="vm.loading"></md-progress-circular>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

Controller:

```
(function(){

  angular
       .module('app')
       .controller('MainController', [
          'navService', '$mdSidenav', '$mdDialog', '$log', '$q', '$state', '$mdToast', 'Pubnub', 'mongolabService', '$scope',
          MainController
       ]);

  function MainController(navService, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog, $log, $q, $state, $mdToast, Pubnub, mongolabService, $scope) {

    var vm = this;

    function showActions($event) {
      var self = this;

      $mdDialog.show({
        controller: [ '$mdDialog', TopUpController],
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/topup.html',
        targetEvent: $event,
        bindToController : true,
        clickOutsideToClose:true
      });

        function TopUpController () {
          var vm = this;
          vm.topUp = topUp;
          vm.loading = false;
          vm.closeDialog = closeDialog;
          function closeDialog() {
            $mdDialog.hide();
          }
          function querySearch (query) {
            return query ? $scope.users.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : $scope.users;
          }

          function topUp(amount) {

            var topUpCallback = {
              error: function(response){
                vm.loading = false;
                showSimpleToast("Error occurred");
                console.log(response);
              }, success: function(response){
                showSimpleToast("Top up success");
              }
            }
            //Amount is undefined
            showSimpleToast("amount: " + amount);
          }

        }
    }

    function showSimpleToast(title) {
      $mdToast.show(
        $mdToast.simple()
          .content(title)
          .hideDelay(2000)
          .position('bottom right')
      );
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: There are some parameters missing here to check this.

Can you include the `ng-controller=""` tag? The best thing to include is a not working demo :-)

does it work when you attach the value to the controller?
something like `vm.topup.amount`? and then just access it from the controller?

Comment: I tried vm.topup.amount but it doesnt work, still undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the amount is just getting undefined when I type on the input. I added allowInvalid to the `<input>` and it worked.

```
ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its strange. change

```
showSimpleToast("amount: " + amount);
```

to

```
showSimpleToast("amount: " + vm.amount);
```

and let see what happens

Comment: He didn't attach the amount anywhere to the controller. So I can't see why this will help

Comment: yes.. i've tried using $scope.topup.amount but it is undefined too.

Comment: Its strange he is getting that weird behavior. And what i know there is no need to declare the variable/scope variable beforehand before you can use it. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: You're not wrong. But it's not necessarily a weird behaviour. I can't see all of the things he did. And I'm not sure why he decided to do things like that.

There are a couple of ways to access scope and controller variables... we need some data to investigate this or a "not working" demo :-)

Comment: You are right. i just read the html very well i guess thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the way you're using topup property like this (just for 1 style coding vm/$scope):
In input

```
<input required type="number" name="amount" ng-model="vm.topup.amount" min="1" ...
```

In button:

```
<md-button ng-click="vm.topUp(topup.amount)" style="margin-right:20px;">
```

And init topup object in your controller:

```
vm.topup = {amount: ''};
```

I think the problem is you didn't init your topup object before use its `amount` property

Comment: CHeck this [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rlery0Og3g01583CBfXA?p=preview). Remove the pattern or change it base on your requirement. Right now if the value is different than 1234 then your model will not take it as value.